# Node.js require file from outside of project scope via package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following project structure. In `errors.js` are error-codes I want to be able to access from the frontend and backend.

```
backend
 - main.js
 - package.json
 - ...
frontend
 - ...
shared
 - errors.js
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "backend",
  ...
  "imports": {
    "#errors": "./../shared/errors.js"
  }
}
```

But node doesn't seem to like paths outside the project scope. How can I import the `errors.js` via relative imports in node? I REALLY don't want to deal with relative paths everywhere.

(The topic name is probably bad and I'm sorry for that.)

Comment: Declare a proper dependency on the errors package?

Comment: @Bergi Well I'm new to NodeJS, so how would I do that exactly?